Converting .htaccess url Rewrite to Nginx rewrite not working
I have been using .htaccess and would recently want to convert to Nginx rewrite as for the url as well, but unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work. I am currently testing it locally in Laragon using Nginx and this is what I have from the configuration file:
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name bsl.test *.bsl.test;
    root "D:/laragon/www/bsl";
    
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass php_upstream;      
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    
    
    charset utf-8;
    
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

I have also tried editing the configuration file to the following and also a few more test, but none of them can get it to work:
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name bsl.test *.bsl.test;
    root "D:/laragon/www/bsl";

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/recover-login/?$ /recover-password.php?type=recovery last;
        rewrite ^/otp-verify/?$ /enter-OTP.php?type=otp last;
        rewrite ^/reset-password/?$ /reset-password.php?type=reset last;

        rewrite ^/modules/?$ /modules.php?type=modules last;

        rewrite ^/user/?$ /user.php?type=user last;
        rewrite ^/user/([^/.]+)/?$ /user.php?type=user&action=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/user/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /user.php?type=user&action=$1&id=$2 last;

        rewrite ^/user-rights/?$ /user.php?type=user-rights last;
        rewrite ^/user-rights/([^/.]+)/?$ /user.php?type=user-rights&action=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/user-rights/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /user.php?type=user-rights&action=$1&id=$2 last;

        rewrite ^/department/?$ /user.php?type=department last;
        rewrite ^/department/([^/.]+)/?$ /user.php?type=department&action=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/department/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /user.php?type=department&action=$1&id=$2 last;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass php_upstream;      
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}

Below is what I have in .htaccess
#START Modules
RewriteRule ^modules/?$ modules.php?type=modules [L]
#END Modules

#START User Management
RewriteRule ^user/?$ user.php?type=user [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/.]+)/?$ user.php?type=user&action=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ user.php?type=user&action=$1&id=$2 [L]
#END User Management

#START User Rights Management
RewriteRule ^user-rights/?$ user.php?type=user-rights [L]
RewriteRule ^user-rights/([^/.]+)/?$ user.php?type=user-rights&action=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user-rights/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ user.php?type=user-rights&action=$1&id=$2 [L]
#END User Rights Management

Please help as I am current stucked.
Thank you

"I can't seem to get it to work" - But you don't seem to have made any attempt to implement the .htaccess rules in to your Nginx config? But also, your Nginx config contains a standard front-controller pattern (to index.php) and there is no indication of this in your .htaccess config?

@MrWhite I have edited my question to include what I have tried but not working. I don't think I understand Nginx yet, because it is my first time trying to use it. With the current Nginx the URL http://localhost:8080/bsl/modules/ is redirected to directory index of the folder "modules" which is wrong. Instead it should read from http://localhost:8080/bsl/modules.php?type=modules
